# Solving a differential equation (Multiple variable calculus)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $f(t)$ be a differentiable in single variable function, prove that $h(x,y) = f(x^2 - y^2)$ satisfies this differential equation:
$$ yh_x + xh_y = 0.$$

What I tried :

$h_x = \dfrac{\partial}{ \partial x} f(x^2 -y^2) = f(x^2-y^2) \cdot 2x$

$h_y = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x^2 -y^2) = f(x^2-y^2) \cdot (-2y)$

And thus:

$yh_x = 2xy f(x^2-y^2)$
$xh_y = -2xy f(x^2-y^2)$

And: $yh_x + xh_y = 2xyf(x^2-y^2) - 2xyf(x^2-y^2) = 0.$

However, I am not sure if my solution is good, from what I've seen, you need to substitute $u = x^2 - y^2$ and use other tricks which I cannot recall.

I just need an approve if this is a good solution / what would you change in it.

Comment: You get $\partial$ by using `\partial` in math mode.

Comment: @Jan Thank I'll update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look again at your derivatives. Applying the chain rule yields for example

$$\frac{ \partial }{\partial x} f(x^2 - y^2) = f'(x^2 - y^2) \cdot 2x.$$

(Note the $f'$, which comes from the outer derivative.)

The rest is then fine, your solution is good.

Comment: Thanks! so I only missed the fact that it should be $f'(x^2 - y^2)$ and not $f(x^2 -y^2)$ ?thanks again!

Comment: Yes, if you replace $f$ everywhere by $f'$, your solution is correct and well-written.

Comment: Thank you so much! - (I will accept your answer once I can - need to wait 8 minutes :-) )

Comment: Hey just a question, doesn't $f'(x^2-y^2)$ counts as an abuse of notation? Because the ' (derivative) is for function on one variable but here y comes into play? Thanks!

Comment: No, since $f$ only depends on one variable, namely $x^2 - y^2$. Of course, $h$ depends on two variables, but this does not matter when writing $f'$.